# How to change color of Vertical header of QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a table widget. i want to set the color of vertical header in CSS.

want to change the color where blue arrow is marked.

I tried the code

```
QHeaderView::section{background-color:rgb(120,120,120);color: white;}
```

but i get this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect for me. You can try it !

```
stylesheet = "::section{Background-color:rgb(190,1,1);border-radius:14px;}"
Table.verticalHeader().setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

Comment: I have already tried that but the area i marked is not changing.

Comment: Is it possible to change a specific cell instead of all the vertical header?

Answer (score -1):

You must also change the table widget background :

```
table.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget > QWidget {background-color: rgb(120,120,120);}")
```